# How to display dataset from astsa package?

Tags: r, dataset, rstudio

I'm trying to use the Lynx dataset from the astsa package to plot as a time series but when I run the code, the global environment shows up as . I'm still very new to using R so I'm confused as to what I'm doing incorrectly. Thank yoU!

```
library(astsa)
data("Lynx")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data` is loaded into the environment.  If we use `data(Lynx)` before loading the package, it would show a warning

```
data(Lynx)
```

> Warning message: In data(Lynx) : data set ‘Lynx’ not found

After loading the package

```
library(astsa)
data(Lynx) # returns nothing if it is loaded
```

Can now work with the Lynx

```
str(Lynx)
#Time-Series [1:91] from 1845 to 1935: 30.1 45.1 49.1 39.5 21.2 ...
```

Or by checking the `ls()`

```
ls()
# [1]"Lynx"
```

or with

```
head(Lynx)
#[1] 30.09 45.15 49.15 39.52 21.23  8.42
```